# Apply different transformation on each dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe(records_002_df) in below format and more columns to be added in future -

```
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+
|RECORD_TYPE|     CLAIM_NUMBER|RECEIVED_DATE|
+-----------+-----------------+-------------+
|        002|     23E002113200|   08/30/2023|
|        002|     23P001125500|   05/30/2023|    
|        002|     23E002114300|   01/30/2024|    
|        002|20223124002830199|   12/31/2022|    
|        002|20223124003270199|   12/31/2022|    
|        002|20223493004410199|   12/31/2022|
```

I need to perform separate transformation on each column, For one of them i tried like below -

```
trans_df=records_002_df.withColumn('RECORD_TYPE',when(records_002_df['RECORD_TYPE'] == '002','In-Network').otherwise('Out-Of-Network'))
```

Above is giving me expected dataframe with required transformation on RECORD_TYPE field.
But I have different transformations to be applied on other columns. Also want to keep the transformation logic in a separate module, so that the spark script should be generic.
Please suggest some ideas how I can achieve this.
Thanks !!

Comment: What do you mean by "spark script should be generic"? Do you mean something like creating a separate module for just the transformation logic and importing that into your main file and applying the respective transformations to the corresponding columns?

Also, for applying more transformations to other columns - you can use method chaining as `your_df.withColumn().withColumn()...` and pass the column names and the functions that you'll import from the transformation module to these methods.

Comment: when you say transformations, what do you mean? are other transformations that you intend to apply to other columns going to be similar to the one you showed (when + otherwise)?

Comment: Thanks @VikasSharma, yes the transformation would be different on each column and when I say generic spark script then I mean to say whenever any future transformations comes in I just need to add the column name and the transformation logic into a separate common file, and no change in original spark script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the transformations into a dictionary with

- key: the wanted column name
- value: a [Column expression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html) that contains the transformation.

In the column expression the dataframe should not be referenced directly but the input data should be referenced by its [column names](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.col.html?highlight=col).

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

transformations = {"RECORD_TYPE": F.when(F.col("RECORD_TYPE") == '002','In-Network')
                                                          .otherwise('Out-Of-Network'),
                   "NEXT_DAY": F.date_add(F.to_date("RECEIVED_DATE", "MM/dd/yyyy"), 1)
}
```

This dict can now be applied to the dataframe:

```python
records_002_df.select([F.col(name) for name in df1.columns - transformations.keys()] # unchanged columns
           + [ transformation.alias(name) for (name,transformation) # transformed columns
              in transformations.items()]) \
         .show()
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|RECEIVED_DATE| CLAIM_NUMBER|RECORD_TYPE|  NEXT_DAY|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   08/30/2023| 23E002113200| In-Network|2023-08-31|
|   05/30/2023|J23P001125500| In-Network|2023-05-31|
|   01/30/2024| 23E002114300| In-Network|2024-01-31|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

The `transformations` dict does not have any references to the original dataframe, so its creation can be moved to another module.

Comment: Thanks @werner just wanted to let you know that I have posted one more question related to pyspark, if you get a chance please check and provide your inputs there as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215198/apply-transformation-on-nested-json-column-in-dataframe